# Angular not passing parameters to $routerOnActivate

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I enter URL like `foo/bar?myVariable=true`
and I have my `$routerOnActivate` method

```
    $routerOnActivate(next, previous) {
        if(next.params.myVariable) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

however params do not contain paramter `myVariable`, how can I pass parameter from querystring to `$routerOnActivate`

Comment: What are you using as a router? and are you actually typing the url like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem with my routing config i have route defined as

```
foo/bar/
```

to make it work with such a route i would have to make url like this

```
foo/bar/?myVariable=true
```

however I changed my route in route config to

```
foo/bar
```

which is much cleaner